# Not able to display the value of Model object attribute using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Below is my controller and html using Spring boot with thymeleaf. I'm not able to display the text value "headers1". Please let me know if i'm missing something.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/tabsDetails1")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getTabsDetails1(@RequestParam String Id, Model m) {       
         m.addAttribute("headers","headers1");
        return "pages/enr :: tab-info";
    }
```

--AJAx Call to get data will call tabsDetails1-------
On click of the button will call showTabsDetails and should show the data using thymeleaf.

```
function showTabsDetails(id) {
            
            var param = '?id=' + $("#id").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url : "tabsDetails1"+param,
                  //  method : 'GET',
                   // data : $form.serialize(),
                    success : function(response) {
                        $('#enrDiv').show();
                    }
                });
        }
```

----enr HTML------

```
<div th:fragment="tab-info"  id="enrDiv" >
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"><b>TEST</b></div>
             <div class="panel-body">
             <h2 th:text="${headers}"></h2>
            </div>
         </div>
</div
```

Also I'm passing an object through fragment in to new Html and I dont see value on the text input with th:field attribute. Weird thing is i'm able to see the value with th:text but not with th:field

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade" th:classappend="${barStat.first} ? 'show active'"  th:id="${h.key}" th:each="h, barStat: ${headers}">
                        <div th:if="${h.key} == 'MY_FORM'">
                             <div  th:replace="~{fragments/myForm :: myHtmlForm(id,${h.value}) }"></div>
                        </div>                           
                </div>
            </div>
```

Below is myHtmlForm fragment code

```
   <div th:fragment="myHtmlForm(id,headers)">
    <div class="setup-content" id="step-5">
        <form  th:action="@{/saveForms}" th:id="${id}" method="post"  th:object="${headers}"  class="form-horizontal" >

         <p th:text="${headers.name}"></p>  

                    <div class="row form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">* Name</label> 
                            <input type="text"  th:text="${headers.name}" class="form-control"> 
                            <!-- <span class="error style="display: none;"> Please enter a Name.</span> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As I'm doing a AJAX call, should I refresh the div after AJAX call?

Comment: Indeed, your AJAX call will get a piece of HTML in its response, but you will have to insert it into the DOM using JavaScript. Alternatively, have a look at [htmx](https://htmx.org/) which could make these kind of things a lot easier without having to write JavaScript yourself. See [TodoMVC with Thymeleaf and HTMX](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/10/04/todomvc-with-thymeleaf-and-htmx/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @WimDeblauwe. I'm able to get data now but when I'm passing the object through fragment its not displaying the fields with th:field. Added my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.